# Colocar cor de fundo do ListView invisível quando usa a barra de rolagem

Tags: android, listview

Na minha aplicação tem um listview e quando eu rolo a barra de rolagem o fundo fica branco , queria deixar invisível , sem nenhuma cor deixar só a cor que já está no fundo da aplicação, alguém sabe?

[image: Normal]

[image: Quando esta Rolando]

Comment: E se não rolares o fundo está transparente?

Comment: e sim, o fundo da minha aplicação e azul e uma imagem e ela tem uma borda , ai quando rola o fundo fica branco e tampa a borda

Comment: dá para tirar um print?

Comment: Olha ai coloquei o print

Comment: tens no teu XML do `LisvView` o parâmetro                 `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: Tenta adicionar também `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` e depois diz como ficou

Comment: Funcionou , mais não ajudou muito em um dos meus problemas

Comment: Porque não ajudou ?

Comment: ajudou , mais e que mesmo invisivel o fundo o list estava ficando por cima da borda mais coloquei um android:paddingBottom="50dp" e funcionou. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de ter no teu XML do `LisvView` o parâmetro:
                 `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` e também o parâmetro:
 `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"`